# How can i implement agora video toolkit inside my game developed in c++

Tags: agora.io

I have developed a game using C++ and require to add the video/audio chat options embedded in the game. Can someone suggest ways to do them?

Comment: Which platform are your working on? What's the OS?

Answer (score 0):

Agora offers a C++ SDK, check out the ["Agora Windows" SDK QuickStart Guide](https://docs.agora.io/en/Video/start_call_windows?platform=Windows). it's labeled Windows but it is the C++ SDK as can be noted by the C++/ All Platforms designation in the API Documentation: https://docs.agora.io/en/Video/API%20Reference/cpp/index.html